# BDD based on 1-liner requirements

Tags: requirements, bdd

In our team, the product owner only gives us a 1-liner summary. The developers then come up with a [PoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept), which the product owner reviews and the cycle repeats.

The challenge here is 2-fold:

1. Time: We have to create the PoCs asap, so that they can be reviewed
2. The Developers are actually defining the look and feel of the product - a lot of UI PoC and some controller development to back it up. But [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) doesn't gel into the "creative" process of product envisioning. Typically, BDD requires you to take a product specification, and then codify it using Jasmine etc.

Can any BDD experts please suggest a way to blend the creative thinking process with BDD?

Comment: Why are you trying to shoehorn a totally different process in?  What makes you think it will be accepted?

Comment: Because I want to use *DD to be assured that the code that goes into production eventually is well tested and has no hidden problems.

Comment: OK, but they are not the only way to achieve that goal and they are also large, overarching philosophies that don't sound to be compatible with the way your company does things at all.  This does not sound like a project that's destined for success.

Comment: Please elaborate on "other ways to achieve the goal". Thats the reason I'm asking the question. If BDD isn't right for my case, then what is?

Comment: For what it's worth, an "innovative" feature will typically not have a robust specification, it grows organically through such cycles. That being said, we want to ensure that innovation doesn't sacrifice quality.

Comment: Well, for instance, why not do rapid prototyping and then start making tests when you're relatively confident you won't want to make sweeping changes to how things work?  I realize that's not fashionable but it's another way to end up where you're trying to go.  I'm sure there are other approaches, but my point, ultimately, is that if you aren't getting detailed specs then a methodology that starts from the principle that everything must have detailed specs is a poor fit.

Comment: Fair point, that is what we are doing right now, I'm trying to check if anyone has been able to bridge this gap.

Answer (score 8):

Forget a moment about the "BDD buzzword", and let's talk about what we called it the last decades: **functional specs**. If you think the specs you get from your PO are not detailed enough, write the missing parts on your own. This gives you lots of room for creative discussion, before actually starting to code, but will also help you to remember what decisions you have made, for example, a week ago. It can also help you to plan which tests you will have to write. This leaves you also with some room to fix errors or inconsistencies you might detect in your "detailed spec" when you are or actually implementing the related features (maybe with some prototyping first). So the fact you are writing some things down before you start to code has nothing to do with any "waterfall model".

Just be careful to **stay pragmatic** and don't dive more into the details as your team needs to work effectively. To find the right balance, you will probably need to gather some experience by doing it. And if you think the "BDD kind" of spec writing is the right tool for you and your team, try it out . But be careful, BDD is a somewhat formal way of writing specs, which has a high risk of becoming non-pragmatic. If you are under the impression it will hinder your creativity, don't use it.

Joel Spolsky wrote a great four-part series about software specs, why you need them and how to write them painlessly, [here is the link to the first part](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html), you will find there links to the other parts as well. Though more than 10 years old (far older than the term BDD), I heavily recommend to read it.

Comment: And here's [Eric Lippert on the importance of having a spec](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/19/always-write-a-spec-part-one.aspx)

Comment: Heartily agree that for "regular" projects its important to have a specification. But when you are on a team that regularly undertakes "innovation sprints" where you start off on a 1-liner requirement/goal and "see how it goes" you don't have any spec. The spec changes by the day. I'm interested to know if anyone has used BDD in that scenario.

Comment: Specs are good, but you shouldn't glorify them either. Implementation, unlike specification, is always unambiguous (assuming it's decent). And makes behavior easier to judge. If you're building something that can be entirely specified beforehand, I do wonder whether it's worth building at all (as you're probably just rehashing things that exist already, maybe that you have even built variations of in the past). I think it's best to build and toy with a minimum viable version of a feature before fleshing out the spec.

Comment: @user90766: as I said be pragmatic. If you think BDD is too "upfront" or too formalized and hinders your ceativity, but 1-liners maybe too sloppy for a quality product, then you will probably need something in between. That's why I posted you the link to Joel's article, which shows a very pragmatical approach.

Comment: @back2dos: No, I do not glorify specs, too. But 1-liners will be often just "not enough". And Joel's example is the opposite of "specifying something entirely beforehand", its more a reminder of think first and come up with a concept before start hacking. Note also about the responsibility: as long as I (as a coder) write down the concept, I can still be the "creative guy", noone is taking that away from me.

Comment: @DocBrown: I wasn't really suggesting that you are. My point was more that sometimes just bashing out a PoC and then taking a step back is the best tool for being "creative". You can only really learn through failure. Unless you're doing the nth reiteration of a design, you have a lot to learn about the problem domain and should thus give your design the chance to fail *early*. Otherwise you risk being committed to fundamental design flaws that you just didn't see emerge on the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to park your first point if I may. If the deliverable is highly desirable and will produce tangible benefit, there will naturally be a clamour for it to be delivered speedily.

The second point interests me. To my mind, if the business have a requirement for an interface to behave in a certain way, this too should come under BDD's given-when-then process.

However, it sounds to me like they're unsure of what they actually want until they see it, so I'd be inclined to decouple this from rest of the development so it can be produced in isolation. Then once the business is happy with the interface, stitch this into the main deliverable and test as normal.